# viewForAnnotation throws error when returning nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

So I have implemented my viewForAnnotation as such

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
static NSString *identifier = @"id";

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[infl8Node class]]) {
    NSLog(@"Creating a pin");
    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}

return nil;
}
```

However I am still running into this error:

```
2012-11-18 22:12:35.608 Infl8[5960:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[infl8Node coordinate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x846f460'
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this error? I have traced it to the case where the annotation is of the class MKUserLocation.

EDIT:
Here is the infl8Node.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface infl8Node : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *accountName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *address;

- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict;
- (MKMapItem *) mapItem;
@end
```

Comment: Actually, that error says the infl8Node class doesn't implement the coordinate property.  Can you post the infl8Node.h?

Comment: ..and make sure it is #imported properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol must implement the `coordinate` property.

The `infl8Node` class does not appear to do that which is why you are getting that `unrecognized selector` error.

At a minimum, the class will need to implement a `coordinate` method which  returns the coordinate associated with its location.